# The following classes could not be instantiated: - com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView

Tags: android, android-studio, youtube

enter image description hereIn my app i have created a YouTube client on android by using this tutorial: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-youtube-client-on-android--cms-22858
in which one of the activity is  PlayerActivity to play the videos. But on creating this activity, i have get this error on graphical view: "The following classes could not be instantiated:- com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView".... Although i have paste the YouTube Player and other libraries in libs folder and also added dependencies.
Every kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your build.gradle

```
dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
        compile files('libs/mylib.jar')
    }
```

Comment: I have arleady added this in build.gradle